# "rails s" using Ruby 1.8.7 instead of Ruby 1.9.3 (OS X 10.7.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, rubygems

Odd problem, trying to figure out what is going on here with my fresh install.

I installed Ruby 1.9.3 using homebrew. I installed Rails 3.2.0 using ruby gems. I then created a test application with `rails new test_app` to make sure everything looked okay in the test environment. Somehow, the rails environment is using 1.8.7 instead of 1.9.3.

When doing a `ruby -v`, I get this:

```
overcast:test_app joe$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
```

But when running `rails s` I get this:

```
overcast:test_app joe$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2012-01-21 23:21:35] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-01-21 23:21:35] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10) [universal-darwin11.0]
```

And, obviously, when looking at the rails environment webpage at localhost:3000 I am showing 1.8.7 instead of 1.9.3. I've edited /etc/paths to have /usr/local/bin at the top based on some answers I've found here, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Addendum**: The same situation happens when installing and attempting to use Ruby through RVM.

Comment: You should use rvm and create a gemset for your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running mac os x you have ruby 1.8 preinstalled. Use RVM or rbenv if you want to have more than one ruby version installed.

Comment: Same thing happens with RVM. I tried installing 1.9.2 with RVM and setting it as a default just in case being bleeding edge with 1.9.3 was the problem. ruby -v displayed the currently selected RVM version, but rails s insisted on using 1.8.7. I'll add this to the question because it was something I considered.

Comment: rails s will only start the server. Under what ruby version did you install rails? what do $which rails and $which ruby give you?

Comment: using RVM: /usr/bin/rails and /Users/joe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby respectively. Without RVM, $which ruby is: /usr/local/bin/ruby

Comment: your rails gem need to be installed under the ruby you use, maybe using gemsets can help you to manage your gems and ruby versions. Check the documentation for RVM if that is what you use.

Comment: Ah! You know what, I think that is the problem! I'll roll things back and start with RVM instead of homebrew. Thanks!

Comment: oh No! No! you do not want to uninstall homebrew. Uninstall your system rails and system ruby version if you want to uninstall something : )

Comment: Haha, no believe me, homebrew is staying! It's much too useful to be getting rid of! But I am definitely thinking of junking the current ruby and rails set up and starting over using RVM to manage everything. It seems like something strange is going on with the current mishmash of RVM ruby + homebrew ruby + system ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Homebrew not so bad :)
You may use `rbenv`. It is ruby version manager.
My success story for MAC OS X 10.8.2 is:

- install Homebrew
- change PATH in /etc/paths (`/usr/local/bin` need to be first)
- install rbenv and ruby-build (it is plugin for rbenv) using homebrew
- create ~/.profile with content:

  ```
  export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/opt/rbenv

  if which rbenv > /dev/null; then
      eval "$(rbenv init -)"
  fi
  ```
- install last stable ruby version using `rbenv install 1.9.3-p374`
- change default ruby version using `rbenv global 1.9.3-p374`
- update gem using `gem update --system` (optional)
- install rails `gem install rails`
- ...
- Profit :)

Answer (score 0):

```
bundle exec rails server
```

Should work just fine. It also worked for me to close the terminal and open a new one.

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple versions of ruby, I recommend you use [RVM](http://rvm.io/)

Install it https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Use: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm#usage

To view all versions of ruby use "rvm list"

and set default version "rvm --default version"

Answer (score 0):

> sudo update-alternatives --config gem

and select your verison!